# How can I pass function's return value as parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have lots of functions similar to `FunctionOne`. Difference in these is `five = this.methodTwo(two, three, four, five)`. I don't want to repeat code. For doing that, how can I pass function's return value as parameter?

```
class MyClass {
    FunctionOne(one, two, three, four, five) {
        //some code here
        one = "my one";
        two = "my two";
        five = this.FunctionTwo(two, three, four, five); //How can I pass this as parameter
        one[five] = "something";
        return one;
    }
    FunctionThree(one, two, three, four, five) {
        //some code here
        one = "my one";
        two = "my two";
        five = this.FunctionFour(two, three, four, five); //Everything in FunctionThree is same as FunctionOne except this statement
        one[five] = "something";
        return one;
    }

    FunctionTwo(two, three, four, five) {
        //some code
        return five;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show examples of the repeated code? I don't get what you mean by "I pass function's return value as parameter".

Comment: @Carcigenicate added code to show example of the repeated code

Comment: You _could_ pass the function to call as a parameter, like `FunctionX(one, two, three, four, five, fn) {…}` and could be called like `x = FunctionX(h, i, j, k, l, FunctionOne)`

Comment: @StephenP, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to take the *function* as another parameter.

Similar to your FunctionOne, FunctionTwo etc. you could have `FunctionX` which does the common work and calls the passed function which, as a parameter, can be varied by the caller.

That would look something like this:

```
// added 'fn', the function to call, as the sixth parameter
FunctionX(one, two, three, four, five, fn) {
    //some code here
    one = "my one";
    two = "my two";
    five = fn(two, three, four, five);
    one[five] = "something";
    return one;
}
```

Now you can call this elsewhere like:

```
let x = FunctionX(h, i, j, k, l, FunctionOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

So,

- By doing this:

  ```
  five = this.FunctionTwo(two, three, four, five)
  ```

you calling function 'FunctionTwo' with params (two, three, four, five) and assigning result of function 'FunctionTwo' to variable 'five'

- By doing this:

  ```
  five = this.FunctionTwo
  ```

you are assigning function 'FunctionTwo' instance to variable 'five', but NOT calling it yet.

Basically later in the code you can do something like that:

```
five(two, three, four)
```

- Not really clear what you want, but you can pass 'this' in to the 'FunctionTwo' and assign result to current object.

Ignore if nothing helps to you :)